# How to handle root route with parameter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

So I've got the current route setup:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'MainController@index');
```

This is for passing in a id through `/` but I would also like:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

but it keeps handling `admin` as a URL parameter rather than it's own route, is there a way of distinguishing between the two?

Comment: Did you try to declare `Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');` before `Route::get('/{id}', 'MainController@index');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move this route to the end of the routes file to make all other routes similar to `'/admin'` work:

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'MainController@index');
```